# Java SMS USb modem

Tags: java, sms, modem, smslib

I'm trying to send SMS using a USB modem (I have a  D-Link Usb Modem).
I just found SmsLib but what I don't know is how to use a USB modem.
The examples I have found are for Serial Modems and I did not found any example for a USB modem.
Do I need to map the usb port as a serial port ? Using what ?
My modem is supported by SmsLib.
Do you have any idea about how to configure a USB modem with SmsLib ?

(I have a MacBook).

Answer (score 3):

all USB modem are available in system as COM (serial port). if OS is windows, open device manager and check modem properties. port number is visible there. i am using one and it is functioning well with SMSLib based java app.

Answer (score 2):

No MacBook experience, but here are the steps in Linux.

1. use dmesg to find the name given the modem by the OS, e.g. /dev/ttyACM0
2. ln -sf /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyS0
3. use ls to ensure that /dev/ttyS0 is writable by you
4. update javax.comm.properties with /dev/ttyS0 (when using Java Comm)
5. patch /dev/ttyS0 into the send and receive examples

Java Comm doesn't seem to support OS/X but RxTx does.
HTH. Good luck!